# rsync -r to existing folder

Tags: rsync

If I run this:

```
rsync -r /a/b/c /a/d/e
```

I will get this:

```
/a/d/e/c
```

but I am looking for just:

```
/a/d/e
```

this will not solve this problem:

```
rsync -r /a/b/c/* /a/d/e
```

because the above will skip dot-files (hidden files).
How can I solve this one  - copying to an existing directory, in this case, folder with name `e`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So close...

```
$ rsync -r /a/b/c/ /a/d/e/
```

Comment: trailing forward slashes on both? or just the destination?

Answer (score 10):

`rsync` treats the source differently if it ends with a trailing `/`.

- With a trailing `/`: `rsync -r source/ target`

  Result: Creates `target` as a copy of `source`.
- Without a trailing `/`: `rsync -r source target`

  Result: Creates `target/source` as a copy of `source`.

The `rsync` manual mentions this:

> You can think of a
>          trailing `/` on a source as meaning "copy the contents of this directory"
>          as opposed to "copy the directory by name", but in both cases the
>          attributes of the containing directory are transferred to the
>          containing directory on the destination.

Comment: so... back to the question - what if the target already exists and we just want to copy the contents of the source to the target? Can you update your answer to address that?

Comment: @AriesVII It's unclear what you want to get at the end in that case. Do you want to delete the existing files on the target that are not part of the source? If so, use `--delete`. Otherwise, I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: How was my comment unclear? I was asking about how to copy contents of a source directory to a target directory. Anyway, the accepted did what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @AriesVII What's unclear is what you want to happen to whatever files already exists at the destination.

Comment: It was unclear because it wasn't part of the question / comment I made. I think "we just want to copy the contents of the source to the target" is pretty clear. The OP was asking about directories, so you could have derived that the question was about directories. Just read my comment again and I gotta say - It's probably one of the clearest things I've said in the history of me saying things.... ever.